# Abelian categories and axiom (AB5)

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category.

We say that $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies (AB5) if $\mathcal{A}$ is cocomplete and filtered colimits are exact.

In Weibel's Introduction to homological algebra, he states (without proof) that $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies axiom (AB5) iff $\mathcal{A}$ is cocomplete and for all lattices $\{ A_i \}$ of subobjects of $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and all subobjects $B$ of $A$, we have $$ \sum (A_i \cap B) = B \cap \sum A_i.$$

I have been thinking about this for a few days but have been unable to come up with a proof. In the forward direction I can't seem to relate the sum of subobjects and filtered colimits. I have no idea about the backward direction. Could anyone give me a hint?

Note: This is not actually an exercise in Weibel's book, he states it in the appendix on category theory when he is defining axiom (AB5). It is stated without proof in Grothendieck's Tōhoku paper. Also, It is an exercise in Freyd's abelian categories.

Comment: ‘Filtered colimits are exact’ means that they commute with finite limits. An intersection is a finite limit (it is a pullback), and a sum over a lattice is a filtered colimit. Does that help?

Comment: @Zhen: My issue is that I can't see how a sum of sub-objects is a colimit. The only way I know of showing that sums exist in a cocomplete abelian category is to show that the quotient objects have infimums and then take kernel.

Comment: A sum is a pushout (and a direct sum is a coproduct).

Comment: The only way I can think of realising a sum in terms of pushouts is to take cokernels, then pushout, then take the kernel. Is there an easier way?

Comment: That seems like overkill. $A + B$ is the pushout of $A \leftarrow A \cap B \rightarrow B$.

Comment: Thanks for that! you helped me figure out the forward direction.

Comment: Did you check in chapter 3 of Mitchell's "Theory of Categories"? If I remember correctly, Mitchell uses the terminology $C_3$ instead of $AB_5$.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me whether it is clear to you that the equality displayed is to be understood as equality of *subobjects* of $A$ (this is left more than unclear in Weibel and somewhat unclear in Tōhoku).

Comment: @Theo: I'd love to see an example where one has equality of objects and not of subobjects :)

Comment: @Mariano: Oy. What in the world have I produced here? :) I'd love to say "I don't know what on earth I was thinking" but I can't, because I obviously wasn't...

Comment: @Theo Buehler: I don't know whether you can read German, but a detailed treatment of your question can be found in Bodo Pareigis' "Kategorien und Funktoren" chapter.section 4.7 "Grothendieck-Kategorien", where (AB5) is invoked only for totally ordered families of subobjects, then shown to hold for all filtered families (using a typical set-/order-theoretical argument), and then the equivalence with the exactness of the direct limit functor shown (assuming your other blanket hypotheses). Kind regards - Stephan F. Kroneck.

Comment: @bonnbaki: Thanks a lot for this reference; German is fine. That might be what I had in mind. I read this in Schubert's *Kategorien* and got myself confused, but the confusion's gone.

Comment: @Theo: the equalities are equalities of subobjects. Is it not standard use the symbol "=" to mean equality of subobjects?

Comment: DBr: no that's fine. I've got myself confused over a different issue and I left my comments here simply for the sake of honesty. Don't worry about it. The mistake is mine.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I borrowed the ideas from the following books.

Abelian categories with application to rings and modules by Popescu, 1973.

Theory of categories by Mitchell, 1964.

**Notations and Conventions**
We fix a [Grothendieck universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) $\mathcal{U}$.
We consider only categories which belong to $\mathcal{U}$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.
We denote by Ob($\mathcal{C}$) the set of objects of $\mathcal{C}$.
Often, by abuse of notation, we use $\mathcal{C}$ instead of Ob($\mathcal{C}$). 
We denote by Mor($\mathcal{C}$) the set of morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of $\mathcal{C}$.
We denote by dom($f$) the domain of $f$, i.e. $X$ = dom($f$).
We denote by codom($f$) the codomain of $f$, i.e. $Y$ = codom($f$).

**Definition**
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.
Let $X$ be an object of $\mathcal{C}$.
Let $I$ be a small set.
Let $(X_i)_I$ be a family of subobjects of $X$.
If $(X_i)_I$ satisfies the following condition, $(X_i)_I$ is called a *directed family of subobjects* of $X$.

*For any $i, j \in I$, there exists $k \in I$ such that $X_i \subset X_k$ and $X_j \subset X_k$.*

**Lemma 1**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Let $I$ be a small category.
Let $F: I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be a functor.
Let $A$ = colim $F$.
For each $i \in I$, let $f_i:F(i) \rightarrow A$ be the canonical morphism.
For each $i \in I$, let $A_i$ = Im($f_i$).
Since $\mathcal{A}$ is cocomplete, $\sum A_i$ exists.
Then $A = \sum A_i$.

Proof:
Let $B = \sum A_i$.
Let $m:B \rightarrow A$ be the canonical monomorphism.
Since $A_i$ = Im($f_i$) for each $i \in I$,
there exists $g_i:F(i) \rightarrow B$ such that $f_i = mg_i$.
Let $u: i \rightarrow j$ be a morphism of I.
Since $f_i = f_jF(u)$, $mg_i = mg_jF(u)$.
Since $m$ is a monomorphism, $g_i = g_jF(u)$.
Hence there exists $g:A \rightarrow B$ such that $g_i = gf_i$ for each $i$.
Hence $mgf_i = mg_i = f_i$ for each $i$.
Hence $mg = 1_A$.
Hence $A \subset B$.
Hence $A = B$.
**QED**

**Lemma 2**
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cocomplete category.
Let I be a small category.
Let $\mathcal{C}^I$ be the category of functors: $I \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.
Then colim$: \mathcal{C}^I \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ preserves colimits.

Proof:
Let $\Delta: \mathcal{C} → \mathcal{C}^I$ be the diagonal functor,
i.e. for each $X \in \mathcal{C}$ and for each $i \in I$, $\Delta(X)(i) = X$.
Since colim is a left adjoint functor of $\Delta$, it preserves colimits(MacLane: Categories for the working mathematician, Chapter V, Section 5, Theorem 1, p.114).
**QED**

**Lemma 3**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category which satisfies (AB5).
Let $X$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$.
Let I be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let Sub($X$) be the category of subobjects of $X$.
Let $F: I \rightarrow$ Sub($X$) be a functor.

Then $\sum F(i)$ = colim $F$.

Proof:
For each $i \in I$, Let $u_i：F(i) \rightarrow$ colim $F$ be the canonical morphism.
For each $i \in I$, Let $m_i：F(i) \rightarrow X$ be the canonical monomorphism.
Since $(m_i)_I$ is a cocone, it induces a morphism $f$: colim $F \rightarrow X$.
By (AB5), $f$ is mono.
Hence we can regard colim $F$ as a subobject of $X$.
Since $fu_i = m_i$ for each $i$, $F(i) \subset$ colim $F$.

Let $Z$ be a subobject of $X$.
Let $r: Z \rightarrow X$ be the canonical monomorphism.
Suppose $F(i) \subset Z$ for each $i$.
Let $k_i: F(i) \rightarrow Z$ be the canonical monomorphism.
Since $(k_i)_I$ is a cocone, it induces a morphism $g$: colim $F \rightarrow Z$.
For each $i \in I$, $rgu_i = rk_i = m_i$.
Hence $f = rg$.
Hence colim $F \subset Z$.
**QED**

**Lemma 4**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $I$ be a small set.
Let $(X_i)_I$ be a family of subobjects of $X$.
Then $\sum f(X_i) = f(\sum X_i)$.

Proof:
For each $i \in I$, $X_i \subset \sum X_i$.
Hence $f(X_i) \subset f(\sum X_i)$.

Let $Z$ be a subobject of $X$.
Suppose $f(X_i) \subset Z$ for each $i$.
Then $f^{-1}(f(X_i)) \subset f^{-1}(Z)$.
Since $X_i \subset f^{-1}(f(X_i))$, $X_i \subset f^{-1}(Z)$.
Hence $\sum X_i \subset f^{-1}(Z)$.
Hence $f(\sum X_i) \subset f(f^{-1}(Z)) \subset Z$.
**QED**

**Lemma 4.5**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Let $I$ be a small category.
Let $F: I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be a functor.
Let $X$ = colim $F$.
Let $(s_i: F(i) \rightarrow Y)_I$ be a cocone.
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be the morphism induced by the cocone.
Then $f(X) = \sum s_i(F(i))$.

Proof:
For each $i$, let $u_i: F(i) \rightarrow X$ be the canonical morphism.
For each $i$, $fu_i = s_i$.
Hence $f(u_i(F(i)) = s_i(F(i)) \subset f(X)$.

Let $Z$ be a subobject of $Y$.
Suppose $s_i(F(i)) \subset Z$ for each $i$.
For each $i$, $s_i$ induces $t_i: F(i) \rightarrow Z$.
Since $(t_i: F(i) \rightarrow Z)_I$ is a cocone,
it induces $g:X \rightarrow Z$.
Let $m: Z \rightarrow Y$ be the canonical monomorphism.
$mgu_i = mt_i = s_i$ for each i.
Hence $f = mg$.
Hence $f(X) \subset Z$.
**QED**

**Lemma 5**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Let $X$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $I$ be a small set.
Let $(X_i)_I$ be a family of subobjects of $X$.
Then $\bigoplus X/X_i$ = $X/(\sum X_i)$.

Proof:
For each $i \in I$, the following sequence is exact.
$0 \rightarrow X_i \rightarrow X \rightarrow X/X_i \rightarrow 0$.
By Lemma 2, colim preserves cokernels.
Hence, colim $X_i \rightarrow X \rightarrow$ colim $X/X_i \rightarrow 0$ is exact.
By Lemma 4.5, Im(colim $X_i \rightarrow X$) = $\sum X_i$.
Hence colim $X/X_i$ = $X/(\sum X_i)$.
**QED**

**Lemma 5.4**
Suppose the following is a pullback diagaram in an abelian category.
$$\begin{matrix}
A&\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}&B\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
C&\stackrel{h}{\rightarrow}&D
\end{matrix}
$$

Suppose the following sequence is exact.
$0 \rightarrow C \stackrel{h}{\rightarrow}D \rightarrow E$

Then $0 \rightarrow A \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}B \rightarrow E$ is exact.

Proof: Left to the readers.

**Lemma 5.5**
Consider the following commutative diagram with two horizontal exact sequences in an abelian category.

$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow 0$

$0 \rightarrow X' \rightarrow Y' \rightarrow Z' \rightarrow 0$

Suppose the left square is a pullback.
Then $Z \rightarrow Z'$ is mono.

Proof:
We call s the above morphism $Z \rightarrow Z'$.

Let $r:T \rightarrow Z$ be a morphism such that sr = 0.

There exists the following pullback diagaram.
$$\begin{matrix}
P&\stackrel{u}{\rightarrow}&T\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow{r}\\
Y&\stackrel{}{\rightarrow}&Z
\end{matrix}
$$

By Lemma 5.4,
$0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z’$ is exact.

Hence there exists $P \rightarrow X$ such that $P \rightarrow Y = P \rightarrow  X \rightarrow Y$.

Hence $ru$ = 0.
On the other hand, since a pullback of an epimorphism in an abelian category is epi(MacLane Proposition 2, p.199), $u$ is epi.
Hence $r$ = 0.
**QED**

**Lemma 6**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category.
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $Z \subset Y$.
Then $X/f^{-1}(Z)$ is canonically isomorphic to $f(X)/(f(X) \cap Z)$.

Proof:

Consider the following commutative diagram with two horizontal exact sequences.

[image: Diagram]

By Lemma 5.5, $X/f^{-1}(Z) \rightarrow f(X)/(f(X) \cap Z)$ is mono.
Since $X \rightarrow f(X)$ is epi,
$X \rightarrow X/f^{-1}(Z) \rightarrow f(X)/(f(X) ∩ Z)$ is epi.
Hence $X/f^{-1}(Z) \rightarrow f(X)/(f(X) \cap Z)$ is epi.
Hence $X/f^{-1}(Z) \rightarrow f(X)/(f(X) \cap Z)$ is an isomorphism.
**QED**

**Note**
If you are willing to accept [Mitchell's embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell's_embedding_theorem), Lemma 6 will be trivial.

**Lemma 7**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ has the following property.

> Let $A$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$.
>   Let $(A_i)_I$ be a directed family of subobjects of $A$.
>   Then, for every subobject $B$ of $A$, $(\sum A_i) \cap B = \sum (A_i \cap B)$.

Let $f:Y \rightarrow X$ be a morphism of $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $(X_i)_I$ be a directed family of subobjects of $X$.
Then,
$f^{-1}(\sum X_i) = \sum f^{-1}(X_i)$.

Proof:
By Lemma 6, for each $i$, $Y/f^{-1}(X_i)$ is canonically isomorphic to $f(Y)/(f(Y) \cap X_i)$.

Hence $\bigoplus Y/f^{-1}(X_i)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\bigoplus f(Y)/(f(Y) \cap  X_i)$.

By Lemma 5, $Y/\sum f^{-1}(X_i)$ = $\bigoplus Y/f^{-1}(X_i)$.

Hence $Y/\sum f^{-1}(X_i)$ = $\bigoplus f(Y)/(f(Y) \cap X_i)$.

By Lemma 5, $\bigoplus f(Y)/(f(Y) \cap X_i)$ = $f(Y)/\sum (f(Y) \cap X_i)$.

By the assumption, $f(Y)/\sum (f(Y) \cap  X_i)$ = $f(Y)/((\sum X_i) \cap f(Y))$.

By Lemma 6, $Y/f^{-1}(\sum X_i)$ is canonically isomorphic to $f(Y)/((\sum X_i) \cap  f(Y))$.

Hence $Y/\sum f^{-1}(X_i)$ is canonically isomorphic to $Y/f^{-1}(\sum X_i)$.

Hence $f^{-1}(\sum X_i)$ = $\sum f^{-1}(X_i)$.
**QED**

**Lemma 7.3**
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.
Let $X$ be an object of $\mathcal{C}$.
Let Sub($X$) be the category of subobjects of $X$.
Let $I$ be a small set.
Let $(X_i)_I$ be a directed family of subobjects of $X$.
Then there exists a preorder on $I$ making $I$ a filtered category and a functor $F: I \rightarrow$ Sub($X$) such that
$F(i) = X_i$ for each $i \in I$.

Proof: Define $i \leq j$ if and only if $X_i \subset X_j$.
**QED**

**Lemma 7.5**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category.
Let $I$ be a small category.
Let $F: I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be a functor.
Let $i \in I$.
Let $(i\downarrow I)$ be the [coslice category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category) under i.
Let Sub($F(i)$) be the category of subobjects of $F(i)$.
Then there exists a functor $G$: $(i\downarrow I) \rightarrow$ Sub($F(i)$)
such that $G(u)$ = Ker($F(u)$) for each $u \in (i\downarrow I)$.

Proof:Clear.

**Lemma 8**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category.
Let $I$ be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let $F: I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be a functor.
Let $i \in I$.
Let $J$ = {$u \in$ Mor($I$); $i$ = dom($u$)}.
Then (Ker($F(u))$)$_J$ is a directed family of subobjects of $F(i)$.

Proof:
Let $(i\downarrow I)$ be the [coslice category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category) under i.
$(i\downarrow I)$ is clearly a filtered category.
Since $J$ = Ob($(i\downarrow I)$), the assertion follows immediately from Lemma 7.5.
**QED**

**Lemma 8.5**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Let $I$ be a small category.
Let $F: I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be a functor.
Let $S = \bigoplus_i F(i)$, where $i$ runs over every object of $I$.
Let $m_i: F(i) \rightarrow S$ be the canonical monomorphism for each $i \in I$.
Let $M$ = $\sum_u$ Im($m_i - m_jF(u)$), where $u$ runs over every morphism of $I$ and $i$ = dom($u$), $j$ = codom($u$).
Let $\pi:S \rightarrow S/M$ be the canonical epimorphism.
Let $f_i = \pi m_i$ for each $i \in I$.
Then $S/M$ = colim $F$ with canonical morphisms $f_i: F(i) \rightarrow S/M$ for each $i \in I$.

Proof:Left to the readers.

**Lemma 8.6**
Let $I$ be a [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let $V$ be a non-empty finite subset of Ob($I$).
Let $T$ be a finite subset of Mor($I$) such that dom($u$) $\in V$ and codom($u$) $\in V$ whenever $u \in T$.
Then there exists $p \in$ Ob($I$) and a morphism $f_i: i \rightarrow p$ for each $i \in V$ with the following property.

> For each $u:i \rightarrow j$ in $T$, $f_i = f_ju$.

Proof:
There exists $q \in I$ such that there exists a morphism $g_i:i \rightarrow q$ for each $i \in V$.
Let $u:i \rightarrow j$ in $T$.
There exists $r_u \in I$ and a morphism $h_u:q \rightarrow r_u$ such that
$h_ug_i = h_ug_ju$.
There exists $r \in I$ such that there exists a morphism $r_u \rightarrow r$ for each $u \in T$.
Hence, for each $u:i \rightarrow j$ in $T$ there exist a morphism $g_{u, i}: i \rightarrow r$ and a morphism $h_{u, j}: j \rightarrow r$ such that $g_{u, i} = h_{u, j}u$.

For each $i \in V$, let $G_i$ be the set {$g_{u, i}: i$ = dom($u$), $u \in T$},
and let $H_i$ be the set {$h_{u, i}: i$ = codom($u$), $u \in T$}.
Let $S_i = G_i \cup H_i$ for each $i \in V$.
By the properties of a filtered category, we can assume that $S_i$ consists of one morphism $f_i$ with a common codomain $p$ for each $i \in V$.
If $S_i$ is empty, we can assume that there exists a morphism $f_i:i \rightarrow p$ which has no condition.
**QED**

**Lemma 9**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ has the following property.

> Let $A$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$.
>   Let $(A_i)_I$ be a directed family of subobjects of $A$.
>   Then, for every subobject $B$ of $A$, $(\sum A_i) \cap B = \sum (A_i \cap B)$.

Let I be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let $F: I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be a functor.
For each $i$, let $f_i: F(i) \rightarrow$ colim($F$) be the canonical morphism.
Then, for each $i$, Ker($f_i$) = $\sum$ Ker($F(u)$), where $u$ runs over every morphism such that $i$ = dom($u$).

Proof:
We use the notations of Lemma 8.5.
Let $T$ be a subset of Mor($I$).
Let $M_T$ = $\sum_{u \in T}$ Im($m_i - m_jF(u)$), where $i$ = dom($u$), $j$ = codom($u$).
Then $M = \sum_T M_T$, where T runs through all *finite* subsets of Mor($I$).
Hence, by Lemma 8.5 and Lemma 7, Ker($f_i$) = $m_i^{-1}(M)$ = $\sum_T m_i^{-1}(M_T)$,
where T runs through all *finite* subsets of Mor($I$).
It suffices to prove:
For each finite subset $T$ of Mor($I$), $m_i^{-1}(M_T) \subset$ Ker($F(u)$) for some $u \in$ Mor($I$) such that  $i$ = dom($u$).

Let $V$ be the set of $k \in I$ such that $k$ = $i$ or $k$ = dom($u$) or $k$ = codom($u$) for some $u \in T$.

Since $I$ is filtered, by Lemma 8.6, there exists $p \in$ Ob($I$) and a morphism $v_k: k \rightarrow p$ for each $k \in V$ with the following property.

> For each $u \in$ Mor($I$) such that k = dom($u$) $\in V$ and $j$ = codom($u$) $\in V$, $v_k = v_ju$.

We define $f:S \rightarrow F(p)$ as follows.
Let $k$ be any object of $I$.
If $k \in V$, $fm_k = F(v_k)$, otherwise $fm_k = 0$.

For each $u \in T$, let $k$ = dom($u$), $j$ = codom($u$).
Then $f(m_k - m_jF(u))$ = $F(v_k) - F(v_j)F(u)$ = $0$.
Hence, by Lemma 4, $f(M_T)$ = $0$.
Since $m_i(m_i^{-1}(M_T)) \subset M_T$, $0$ = $f(m_i(m_i^{-1}(M_T)))$ = $F(v_i)(m_i^{-1}(M_T))$.
Hence $m_i^{-1}(M_T) \subset$ Ker($F(v_i)$) as required.
**QED**

**Proposition 1**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category.
Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ has the following property.

> Let $A$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$.
>   Let $(A_i)_I$ be a directed family of subobjects of $A$.
>   Then, for every subobject $B$ of $A$, $(\sum A_i) \cap B = \sum (A_i \cap B)$.

Then $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies (AB5).

Proof:
Let $I$ be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
By Lemma 2, colim$: \mathcal{A}^I \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ preserves colimits.
In particular, it preserves cokernels.
Hence it is right exact.
It suffices to prove that it preserves monomorphisms.

Let $f: F \rightarrow G$ be a monomorphism of $\mathcal{A}^I$.
Let $K$ = Ker(colim($f$)).
For each i, let $u_i: F(i) \rightarrow$ colim $F$ be the canonical morphism.
Let $A_i$ = $u_i(F(i))$ for each i.
Since $I$ is a filtered category, $(A_i)_I$ is a directed family of subobjects of colim $F$.
By Lemma 1, colim $F$ = $\sum A_i$.
By the assumption, $K$ = $(\sum A_i) \cap K = \sum (A_i \cap K)$.
Suppose $K \neq 0$.
There exists $k \in I$ such that $A_k \cap K \neq 0$.
Since $A_k$ = Im($u_k$), $u_k^{-1}(A_k \cap K) \neq 0$.
Let $M = u_k^{-1}(A_k \cap K)$.
Then $u_k(M) \neq 0$.
For each i, let $v_i: G(i) \rightarrow$ colim $G$ be the canonical morphism.
$v_k(f_k(M))$ = (colim $f$)($u_k(M)$) = (colim $f$)($A_k \cap K$) $\subset$ (colim f)($K$) = $0$.
Hence $f_k(M) \subset$ Ker($v_k$).
By Lemma 9, $f_k(M) \subset \sum$ Ker($G(t)$), where $t$ runs over every morphism such that $k$ = dom($t$).

By Lemma 8 and the assumption, $f_k(M)$ = $\sum$ (Ker($G(t)$) $\cap f_k(M)$).
Since $f_k$ is mono,  $M$ = $f_k^{-1}(f_k(M))$.
By Lemma 7, $M$ = $f_k^{-1}(f_k(M))$ = $f_k^{-1}(\sum$ (Ker($G(t)$) $\cap f_k(M)))$ = $\sum f_k^{-1}$(Ker($G(t)$ $\cap f_k(M))$.
For each morphism $t: k \rightarrow j$, Let $N_t = f_k^{-1}$(Ker($G(t)$) $\cap f_k(M))$.
Then $G(t)f_k(N_t) = 0$.
Since $G(t)f_k = f_jF(t)$, $f_jF(t)(N_t) = G(t)f_k(N_t) = 0$.
Since $f_j$ is mono, $F(t)(N_t) = 0$.
Hence, by Lemma 9, $u_k(N_t) = 0$.
Hence, by Lemma 4, $u_k(M) = u_k(\sum N_t) = \sum u_k(N_t) = 0$.
This is a contradiction.
**QED**

**Proposition 2**
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a cocomplete abelian category satisfying (AB5).
Let $A$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$. 
Let $(A_i)_I$ be a directed family of subobjects of $A$.
Then, for every subobject $B$ of $A$, $(\sum A_i) \cap B = \sum (A_i \cap B)$.

Proof:
Let $C = \sum A_i$.
For each i, we have the following exact sequence.

$0 \rightarrow A_i \cap B \rightarrow A_i \rightarrow C/(C \cap B)$

By (AB5), Lemma 7.3 and Lemma 3, we get the following exact sequence.

$0 \rightarrow \sum (A_i \cap B) \rightarrow C \rightarrow C/(C \cap B)$

Hence $(\sum A_i) \cap B = \sum (A_i \cap B)$.
**QED**

Comment: What a shame that this post is community wiki.

Comment: 62 revisions!!!

Comment: Excessive editing automatically turns a question/answer into a community wiki.

Comment: Dear Makoto, I've added the diagram you were asking for. I hope it is fine. Here's the code I used: `0\ar[r] & f^{-1}(Z) \ar[d] \ar[r] & X \ar[r] \ar[d] & X/f^{-1}(Z) \ar[r] \ar[d] & 0 \\ 0 \ar[r] & f(X)\cap Z \ar[r] & f(X) \ar[r] & f(X)/(f(X)\cap Z) \ar[r] & 0` and [presheaf](http://presheaf.com) for your online xypic diagram rendering needs.

Comment: @BrunoStonek Thank you so much.

Comment: @Rasmus: Moderators can reverse that, however seeing how the edits continue the CW will be set once again. If anything when the answer is near done it is going to be a reasonable course of action to flag for a moderator attention for reversing the CW.

Comment: I just accepted this answer. I havent thought about this stuff for a long time (nearly a year!) but the amount of effort put in to your answer is astounding! well done

Comment: @DBr Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Removing CW has permanent effect, so there is no harm in doing it now.

Comment: @GenericHuman: I didn't know that.

Comment: I've removed CW from this post.